# Unmanaged to managed callback much slower when target is in another AppDomain

Tags: performance, c++-cli, interop, clr

I'm calling managed code from unmanaged code using a delegate. When I call into managed code in the default AppDomain I'm measuring an average of 5.4ns per call. When I calling to a second AppDomain I'm measuring 194ns per call. (default VS2017 x86 release configuration, not running under the debugger).

Why is performance so much lower when calling into an AppDomain that isn't the default? Since I'm coming from the unmanaged side, which has no knowledge of AppDomains I would expect to be calling straight into the target domain. However, the performance hit would imply that the delegate is calling into the default domain then marshaling to the real target. I do see `UM2MDoADCallBack` when stepping through the disassembly. Which shows up under `WrongAppDomain:` in [UMThunkStub.asm](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/amd64/UMThunkStub.asm)

How can I prevent this unnecessary marshaling and call directly into a specific AppDomain?

The code I'm using to test this is below.

```
#pragma unmanaged
#include <wtypes.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cwchar>

typedef void (__stdcall *ManagedUpdatePtr)();

struct ProfileSample
{
    static uint64_t frequency;
    uint64_t startTick;
    wchar_t* name;
    int count;

    ProfileSample(wchar_t* name_, int count_)
    {
        name = name_;
        count = count_;

        LARGE_INTEGER win32_startTick;
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&win32_startTick);
        startTick = win32_startTick.QuadPart;
    }

    ~ProfileSample()
    {
        LARGE_INTEGER win32_endTick;
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&win32_endTick);
        uint64_t endTick = win32_endTick.QuadPart;

        uint64_t deltaTicks = endTick - startTick;
        double nanoseconds = (double) deltaTicks / (double) frequency * 1000000000.0 / count;

        wchar_t buffer[128];
        swprintf(buffer, _countof(buffer), L"%s - %.4f ns\n", name, nanoseconds);
        OutputDebugStringW(buffer);

        if (!IsDebuggerPresent())
            MessageBoxW(nullptr, buffer, nullptr, 0);
    }
};

uint64_t ProfileSample::frequency = 0;

int CALLBACK
WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, PSTR, INT)
{
    LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
    ProfileSample::frequency = frequency.QuadPart;

    ManagedUpdatePtr GetManagedUpdatePtr();
    auto managedUpdate = GetManagedUpdatePtr();

    //Warm stuff up
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
        managedUpdate();

    const int num = 10000000;
    {
        ProfileSample p(L"ManagedUpdate", num);

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < num; i++ )
            managedUpdate();
    }

    return 0;
}

#pragma managed
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Diagnostics;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

ref struct ManagedObject : MarshalByRefObject
{
    ManagedUpdatePtr
    GetManagedUpdatePtr()
    {
        auto delegate = gcnew Action(this, &ManagedObject::ManagedUpdate);

        IntPtr fPtr = Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(delegate);
        return (ManagedUpdatePtr) fPtr.ToPointer();
    }

    void ManagedUpdate()
    {
        //Debug::WriteLine("\n\nManagedUpdate ({0})", (Object^) AppDomain::CurrentDomain->FriendlyName);
    }
};


ManagedUpdatePtr
GetManagedUpdatePtr()
{
    auto pluginDomain = AppDomain::CreateDomain("Plugin Domain");
    auto managedObject = (ManagedObject^) pluginDomain->CreateInstanceAndUnwrap("ManagedHelper", "ManagedObject");

    return managedObject->GetManagedUpdatePtr();
}
```

Comment: Yes, crossing AppDomains requires marshaling (via remoting).

Comment: How am I even crossing AppDomains? I'm directly calling a delegate in a specific domain. There's no other domain involved that I'm aware of.

Comment: Actually, you are calling a native function pointer to a native stub, the stub knows everything it needs to invoke the delegate, including how to marshal to the correct ApDomain.

Comment: Come to think of it, it probably marshals the delegate to the current AppDomain before invoking it rather than marshaling to the target AppDomain before calling the original delegate. The test would be how it behaves when invoking a method on a serializable object rather than a subclass of MarshalByRefObject.

Comment: @BrianReichle That's exactly what appears to be happening. Using Serializable removes the performance hit, but that's because the method is being called in the default AppDomain on a copy of the object. The real question is why is the delegate marshaling into the default AppDomain and how do I make it not do that?

Comment: Ultimately, most managed objects can only exist in one AppDomain (string being the only exception that I am aware of). If you want to access an object that is in another AppDomain, then either that object must be marshaled to the current AppDomain (this happens when the object is serializable) or the call must be marshaled to the owning AppDomain (if the object is a MarshalByRefObject from another AppDomain, then you will actually operate on a TransparentProxy which marshals the call for you).

Comment: I believe the original question is perhaps unclear. I'm starting from unmanaged code. Unmanaged code isn't in an AppDomain. It calls into one. So why would it call into the *wrong* domain just to marshal into the right one? Why isn't it calling directly into the correct one from the start? Obviously it has to have some way to resolve domains if it's consistently calling into the default one, which is nice and fast, so how can that be directed? There's no reason I should ever have to touch the 'wrong' AppDomain and take a marshaling penalty.

Comment: Maybe this Blogpost may help: http://lambert.geek.nz/2011/12/appdomains-and-unmanaged-callbacks-redux/